# iMessages not showing up in Logs

Tags: apple-id, messages, iphone

When browsing my "MyVerizon" call/text logs I noticed that whole conversations that were held via IMessage were omitted from the log. While conversations on my other iPhone that were IMessages from same iPhone/sender/number/etc... DO show up. Any idea what would cause this? Would sending IMessages to the email/Apple ID address rather then the cell # accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

*iMessages* don't go through your cell phone provider so they don't necessarily know about them.  *iMessages* go through your network connection so to your provider they look just like any other network/internet/browser traffic.

If your text messages were from Apple device to Apple device (using *iMessage* for both sides), it's not going to show up on the provider logs.

If your text messages were from your iPhone (or other Apple device) to a non-apple device or an Apple device without a network connection but still connected to the cell network, that **does** go through your cell provider.  They will have a log of those messages.  You can tell which ones those are because the chat bubble on the Apple device is green instead of blue.

Comment: Yeah I get that. Yes, all 3 phones in question are Iphones. I have 2 lines/2 Iphones. The guys number shows when he and I IMessage on the one Iphone. However, when he IMessages the other line/iphone onmy account. It isnt logging through my provider. All other Imessages I send/recieve through other people are logged as well. It's only the conversations on the one particular Iphone FROM this one contact dont log.Sorry if I wasnt Clear in my first question.